# Android studio checkout from Git nothing happens

Tags: git, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 0.4.6 on latest Linux Mint x64.
The issue is, when I'm trying to checkout from VCS Git on the welcome screen, nothing happens, no errors and such. When TEST button is pressed, I get the "Repository test has failed.". 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed Git on the machine and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to point to where Git is installed:

Settings > Version Control > Git Path to Git executable:

`yourPath\git.exe`